# JAVA: objet Set:: error with the first .add(object)

Tags: java, android, set, treeset

i'm trying to use a Set.
But i have an error on the first occurence add() function.. -innerSetException(futurTask.java:273) -setException(FutureTask.java:124).
So i realy don't get it... I really hope you could help me! here is my code:

```
    public class RetrieveArticleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Set<Article>> {

private List<Article> articles;
private List<Article> products ;
private Set<Article> productsUpdates;

private LoginTaskListener  callbackArticlesReceived;

public RetrieveArticleTask(AutoCompletionActivity  callback) {
    this.articles  = new ArrayList<Article>(200);
    this.products  = new ArrayList<Article>(200);
    this.productsUpdates = new TreeSet<Article>();

    this.callbackArticlesReceived = callback;           
}               

@Override
protected Set<Article> doInBackground(Void... aVoid) {

    try {
        List<ArticleResult> articleResults = RetailReloadWebServicesArticle.getListArticlesAll();

        for(ArticleResult articleResult : articleResults ){ 
            articles.add(new Article(articleResult));
            System.out.println(productsUpdates.size());
            productsUpdates.add(new Article(articleResult));
        }
        System.out.println("article size : " + articles.size());
    } catch (ITException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR   :::" +e);
    }


    try {
        products = RetailReloadApplication.getSqliteOpenHelper().getArticleDao().getAllObjects();
    } catch (ITException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(products.size());
    for(Article product : products ){ 
        productsUpdates.add(product);
    }



    try {
        if(productsUpdates != null){
            for(Article productUpdate : productsUpdates ){ 
                RetailReloadApplication.getSqliteOpenHelper().getArticleDao().addOrUpdateObject(productUpdate);
            }
        }
    } catch (ITException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return productsUpdates;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Set<Article> articles) {
    System.out.println(articles.size());
    if (null != callbackArticlesReceived)
        callbackArticlesReceived.onLoginTaskFinished(articles);
}

}
```

And here the complete stacktrace:
 so here is the stacktrace:

```
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.retailreload.service.model.result.article.ArticleResult is not Comparable
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.TreeMap.find(TreeMap.java:254)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.TreeMap.putInternal(TreeMap.java:240)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:186)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:113)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.retailreload.task.RetrieveArticleTask.doInBackground(RetrieveArticleTask.java:48)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.retailreload.task.RetrieveArticleTask.doInBackground(RetrieveArticleTask.java:1)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-04 08:13:17.322: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  ... 5 more
```

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace? and post the whole code

Comment: Could you possibly provide a copy of your logcat?

Comment: `List articles` is binded to UI ?

Comment: How are ArticleResult and Article related?

Comment: ArticleResult is the direct objet retreived frome web, and Article is the one stored in the current BDD device.

Comment: can you post the line where you declare and initialize the "RetrieveArticleTask" object?

Comment: Your `Article` class must override the `compareTo` method by implementing the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding non-comparable objects to a TreeSet. When you add an object to a TreeSet, that TreeSet will be automatically sorted and here java can't find a way to sort your Article objects because it seems you did not provide one.

If you don't care about sorting, change your TreeSet to a HashSet.
If you care about it, the Article class must implement Comparable interface, OR you can provide a Comparator object when you build your TreeSet.

See TreeSet [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Here is an example Article class :

```
public class Article implements Comparable<Article> {
    private String name;
    private int price;

    //Constructors, getters and setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Article a) {
        return this.name.compareTo(a.name);
    }
}
```

Here Article objects will be sorted by name. The compareTo method must return an integer :

- negative if "this" Article is less than the provided one "a"
- zero if equal to
- positive if greater than "a"

Implement that interface and the compareTo method with the sorting logic you need and it should work.

Comment: please, i have read about provide it a comparator. But i did not understand a way to do this.. can you show me a little more how it's works please?

Comment: i'm new to java, this is to abstract to me. Helps me please :)